# How to give border of andy object in AR Core

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, android-augmented-reality, sceneform

[image]

I am building an application using ARCore where i am display images from server. I want to give a border on image that is displaying on AR surfaces. I have list of colors and on tap of that color i need to set it as a border of AR image. Here i am attaching a ScreenShot of my ARView. I want to get square border of selected color on AR object.